# Use Php in Docker Apache

Tags: php, apache, docker

I'm trying to use docker but I have a lot of problem.
Now i Want to use an apache container and use a volume of my php

my images are

- nimmis/apache
- 5.6-fpm

my docker ps is:

```
85e592d46fcc        nimmis/apache       "/my_init"               3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   apacheBarno
c9bc486563bc        php:fpm             "php-fpm"                15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       9000/tcp               app_php
```

and I Started my apache with this command

```
docker run --name apacheFoo --volumes-from app_php -p 8080:80 -v `pwd`:/var/www/html --rm nimmis/apache
```

When I visit `http://192.168.99.100:8080/`  ( im on mac ) I can see the apache page.

when I visit `http://192.168.99.100:8080/index.php` I get `<?php echo "hello" ?>`

instead of "hello"

Comment: Is the php enable? It looks like the server serves the webpage as it instead of executing it.

Comment: @Auzias, sorry but I don't understand

Comment: @monkeyUser You may benefit from trying one of the non-english stackoverflow sites.

Comment: See the answers. Apache does not support PHP if the PHP support is not installed or enabled.

Comment: Why don't you use the official php image (php:5-apache)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the behavior is that the apache image you are using (https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/apache/, right?) is a plain apache without php support. So it just serves your php code as plain text.

You don't need two images in this case. Instead you need one image running Apache with php module. You can use the official php image (https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

Your Docker file can look like this:

````
```
# see https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
FROM php:5.6-apache

# copy your source into the /var/www/html inside the container
COPY . /var/www/html/
```
````

Now you can build and run it like this

````
```
docker build -t apache-foo-docker .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd):/var/www/html --name apacheFoo apache-foo-docker
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to serve PHP with generic apache image. PHP pages should be interpreted on the server side, which is apache in your case. This means apache (and its container) should have PHP configured and enabled. Maybe you could try https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/apache-php5/ instead?